# Foce visual studio to break in the running

Tags: visual-studio

I have an application(not mine) that just seems to hang. I would like to see what it's trying to process, or if it's processing anything. Is that a button in visual studio that I can click that will break at the point it's trying to process?

Comment: Hit the pause button or select it from the debug menu.

Comment: It's actually Debug | Break all.

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the left side of the editor (the place where you actually edit the text), then you will set a breakpoint on that line. When debugging, if your program reaches that line of code, then Visual Studio will stop running your program and let you debug it.

So just set a breakpoint immediately before where you think the problem is.